# Why does Jaya talk directly to the camera in the film Qarib Qarib Single(2017)?

Tags: character, analysis, qarib-qarib-singlle

Throughout the film *Qarib Qarib Single*, Jaya(Parvathy) talks directly to the camera, whereas Yogi (Irrfan) does not. What does this imply?

Comment: https://mediaindia.eu/cinema/breaking-fourth-wall-bollywood/

Comment: Not seen the movie but fourth wall breaking is not that uncommon in Bollywood. Sometimes it helps the movie too but not always.